# Почему получаю исключение The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Author> .OrderBy(a => a.GetType().GetProperty(__sortBy_0)

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-3.1

Делаю сортировку таким способом

```
 private IQueryable<Author> SortAuthor(string sortBy, string typeSort, IQueryable<Author> authors)
 {

      if (typeSort is "Desc")
      {
          authors = authors.OrderByDescending(a => a.GetType().GetProperty(sortBy).GetValue(a, null));
      }

      if (typeSort is "Asc")
      {
          authors = authors.OrderBy(a => a.GetType().GetProperty(sortBy).GetValue(a, null));
      }

      return authors;
 }
```

В итоге получаю исключение

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Author>
    .OrderBy(a => a.GetType().GetProperty(__sortBy_0).GetValue(
        obj: a, 
        index: null))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить)

Comment: [Оно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1689239/12888024)?

Comment: @aepot  К сожалению не нашел ответа на свой вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А если так попробовать?

```cs
enum SortOrder
{
    Asc,
    Desc
}

private IQueryable<Author> SortAuthor<TKey>(Expression<Func<Author, TKey>> sortBy, SortOrder typeSort, IQueryable<Author> authors)
{
    return typeSort switch
    {
        SortOrder.Desc => authors.OrderByDescending(sortBy),
        _ => authors.OrderBy(sortBy),
    };
}
```

```cs
authors = SortAuthor(a => a.Name, SortOrder.Asc, authors);
```

Comment: А почему `Func<Author, TKey> sortBy`, а не `Expression<Func<Author, TKey>> sortBy`?

Comment: @VladD не знаю, а здесь есть разница? `OrderBy` принимает `Func`.

Comment: Странно, у меня не компилирует в таком виде. Но у меня в проекте EF Core 5.0.1

Comment: @VladD а теперь?

Comment: Разница есть, Func невозможно преобразовать в sql, Expression возможно. Не тот OrderBy смотрите, их много, для IQueryable должен принимать Expression (и возвращать он должен также IQueryable)

Comment: Ну и ответ не отвечает на вопрос "Почему"

Comment: Ну, хм, там cast, он-то, конечно, скомпилируется, но у меня падает в рантайме с исключением «``System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[Program.Entity,System.Int32]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Program.Entity]'.'``»

Comment: @VladD, ну логично, потому что перегрузка не та, как я написал выше

Comment: @АндрейNOP окей, окей, исправил )

Comment: @VladD спасибо!

Comment: @aepot: пожалуйста!

Comment: @PashaPash мне удалить ответ, или что?

Comment: @aepot зачем удалять, хороший ответ. но может, стоит замечание добавить.

Comment: @aepot еще можно попробовать сделать красивое решение через динамическую сборку Expression<Func<Author, TKey>> - раз уж PropertyInfo есть - в https://stackoverflow.com/a/33051225/1988244 есть пример

Comment: @PashaPash возможно, но я не особо разбираюсь в ORM, не имею практики. Так что если надо что-то грамотно дописать в ответ, буду благодарен, если поможете с этим.

Comment: @PashaPash: Только что специально проверил: код в ответе на момент вашего комментария использовал `Queryable.OrderBy`.

Comment: @VladD прав. aepot, похоже, я написал коммент видя старую версию ответа, сорри.